# Interpreting memory consumption of program using pugixml

Tags: c++, profiling, pugixml

I have a program which parses an XML file of ~50MB and extracts the data to an internal object structure with no links to the original XML file. When I try to roughly estimate how much memory I need, I reckon 40MB.

But my program needs something like 350MB, and I try to find out what happens. I use `boost::shared_ptr`, so I'm not dealing with raw pointers and hopefully I didn't produce memory leaks.

I try to write what I did, and I hope someone might point out problems in my process, wrong assumptions and so on.

First, how did I measure? I used `htop` to find out that my memory is full and processes using my piece of code are using the most of it. To sum up memory of different threads and to get a more pretty output, I used http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py which confirmed my observation.

I roughly estimated the theoretical consumption to get an idea which factor lies between the consumption and what it should be at least. It's 10. So I used `valgrind --tool=massif` to analyze memory consumption. It shows, that at the peak of 350MB 250MB are used by something called `xml_allocator` which stems from the `pugixml` library. I went to the section of my code where I instantiate the `pugi::xml_document` and put an `std::cout` into the destructor of the object to confirm that it is released which happens pretty early in my program (at the end I sleep for 20s to have enough time to measure memory consumption, which stays 350MB even after the console output from the destructor appears).

Now I have no idea how to interpret that and hope that someone can help me where I make wrong assumptions or some such.

[image]

The outermost code snippet using `pugixml` is similar to:

```
void parse( std::string filename, my_data_structure& struc )
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(filename.c_str());

    for (pugi::xml_node node = doc.child("foo").child("bar"); node; node = node.next_sibling("bar"))
    {
        struc.hams.push_back( node.attribute("ham").value() );
    }
}
```

And since in my code I don't store `pugixml` elements somewhere (only actual values pulled out of it), I would `doc` expect to release all resources when the function `parse` is left, but looking on the graph, I cannot tell where (on the time axis) this happens.

Comment: Can you show the code triggering such memory usage? According to http://pugixml.org/benchmark/, for 16Mb xml file PugiXML uses only about 27Mb.

Comment: Modified the question to show the principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are incorrect.

Here's how to estimate pugixml memory consumption:

1. When you load the document, the entire text of the document gets loaded to memory. So that's 50 Mb for your file. This comes as 1 allocation from xml_document::load_file -> load_file_impl
2. In addition to that, there's the DOM structure that contains links to other nodes, etc. The size of the node is 32 bytes, the size of the attribute is 20 bytes; that's for 32-bit processes, multiply by 2 for 64-bit processes. This comes as many allocations (each allocation is roughly 32kb) from xml_allocator.

Depending on the density of nodes/attributes in your document, memory consumption can range from, say, 110% of the document size (i.e. 50 Mb -> 55 Mb) to, say, 600% (i.e. 50 Mb -> 300 Mb).

When you destroy pugixml document (xml_document dtor gets called), the data is freed - however, depending on the way OS heap behaves, you may not see it returned to the system immediately - it may stay in process heap. To verify that you can try doing the parsing again and checking that peak memory is the same after the second parse.

Comment: To find out more I removed pugixml and used rapidxml instead. Same result, big memory consumption during the start. I think better than a DOM parser would be a SAX parser or -- even better -- an intermediate format so that I don't have to parse the whole 60MB at the start of my program. Anyway, this was the first time I deeply thought about memory consumption and maybe a good lesson for me. I thank you for the reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178961/if-when-does-the-does-deallocated-heap-memory-get-reclaimed