# delete and memory management

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I've found unexpected results about memory management running the following (sample) code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define BIGNUM 100000000

// sample struct
struct Coordinate {
    uint64_t x;
    uint64_t y;
    uint64_t z;
    Coordinate() {
        x = 1ULL;
        y = 2ULL;
        z = 3ULL;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Coordinate*>* coordinates = new std::vector<Coordinate*>();

    for (int i = 0; i < BIGNUM; ++i)
        coordinates->push_back(new Coordinate());

    // block 1
    for(std::vector<Coordinate*>::iterator it = coordinates->begin(); it != coordinates->end(); ++it)
        delete(*it);

    // block 2
    delete(coordinates);

    std::cout << "end\n";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

On my Ubuntu 14.04:

[image]

The command **ps aux --sort -rss** was performed on `std::cin.get();` 4 times, with small differences:

1) program as is

2) with block 1 commented (basically no delete on every vector's element)

3) with block 2 commented (so no delete on vector)

4) both both blocks 1 and 2 commented.

With my (big) surprise test 1) and 2) have almost the same **RSS / VSZ** results. In simple words it seems that `delete(*it);` doesn't work properly (doesn't free memory). Same conclusion can be achieved with 3) and 4).

On Windows XP (running in VirtualBox) everything is fine and memory is 0-2 MB running the program as is.

Comment: Why are you using `new` `delete` here in first place??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've found the issue in a more complex program. Here is just a simplified example!

Comment: Your _simplified_ example is probably over simplified, because it doesn't reproduce the described behaviour.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I'm just saying that `delete(*it);` seems not working properly, because *ps* returns same _VSZ/RSS_ when delete is commented and when it is not

Comment: As for your _bigger context_ you made sure following [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) properly everywhere, did you? Especially regarding `Coordinate`.

Comment: Just FYI: You allocate so much that in this example program that `std::bad_alloc` is actually thrown on my machine.

Comment: @ChristianHackl so curious. I got 16GB of memory, maybe you are running just 4GB with no swap?

Comment: @c.bear: 4GB memory, Windows 7, standard swap settings (3562 MB). I guess this notebook is slowly getting old for new-generation software... :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl oh, on i7 everything happens in the blink of an eye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because `delete` frees memory doesn't mean that the memory is immediately released back to the operating system for general use. Memory management on modern OSes is [just not that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12178961/560648).

There's nothing wrong here other than your assumptions!

Comment: That's what I thought too. But I really MUST free that memory in my real scenario, since I'm working on a really huge memory consuption program (16GB are eaten very fast). Is there any compiler option or something that can help me?

Comment: @c.bear: No you don't. Your OS is intelligent enough to work this out on its own. Just leave it to do its job and don't put too much stock in these figures you're seeing from `ps`. Consider purchasing a book on operating systems and virtual memory schemes.